# Uniqueness of nonlinear initial boundary valued ODE

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

Consider the ODE $$v'' + f(r) v' + g(v) = 0, v(0) = v_0, v'(0) = v_0',$$
where $(r, \theta)$ represent polar coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $g(x)$ is a locally Lipschitz function on $(0, \infty)$, and $f(x)$ is a positive continuous decreasing function. Can one use some existence uniqueness theorem on ODE's to claim right away that this initial boundary valued problem has unique solution?

Comment: Write it as the first order system $v' = w, w' = -f(r)w-g(v)$. The right hand side is locally Lipschitz continuous in $(v,w)$ and therefore solutions are unique.